# integrate puppeteer in gitlab with gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci, end-to-end, puppeteer

Im currently working on e2e test in Chrome Puppeteer. I am at the stage where it would be ideal to integrate my tests in the development process.

What I want to accomplish is the following: my tests run automated before every deploy to production. If they succeed deployment goes through, if they fail deployment is canceled.

I use a pipeline on gitlab to automate my deployment process. 
So my main question is how can I integrate my puppeteer tests into the gitlab-ci.yml file?

Answer (score 15):

This might be a bit of a hack but mine are running like this:

```
test:
image: node:latest
stage: run
script:
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
- yarn
- yarn test
```

That super long list of libraries are the ones that the puppeteer needs to launch chrome. Ideally you would have a ready docker image but all the premade ones I found did not work for me.

When getting ready for prod you should build your own image that takes from node and installs the dependencies itself.

Comment: A bit tricky but that fixed the problem for me; I was having: `ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome` using `karma`.

Comment: I've installed every libs, but got this error: `ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox! Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly`. I launched Chrome with `--no-sandbox`.

Answer (score 7):

We had the same problem, you need to run the stage on an docker image that provides puppeteer:

```
# run performance monitor
performanceMonitoring:
  stage: performanceMonitoring
  image: alekzonder/puppeteer
  script:
    - yarn run performanceMonitoring
```

Comment: This answer is out of date, the `alekzonder/puppeteer` image has not been updated in over 2 years

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by using a docker image with Puppeteer preinstalled.

This is what your .gitlab-ci.yml` should look like:

```
stages:
  - test

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

.node_template:
  image: buildkite/puppeteer

tests:
  extends: .node_template
  stage: test
  variables:
    CI: "true"
  before_script:
    - echo "checking node version"
    - node -v
    - echo "installing dependencies..."
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm run test
```

I recommend using `buildkite/puppeteer` over `alekzonder/puppeteer`, since it comes with the latest LTS version of node and `alekzonder/puppeteer` doesn't.

Comment: is there anyway you could take a look at my question please? I am having a similar issue creating a working gitlab.ci-yml file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904609/gitlab-codeceptjs-tests-were-working-fine-a-week-ago-now-they-all-cancel-befor

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
variables:
  IMG_BUILD: node:latest
  IMG_TEST: trion/ng-cli-karma
  IMG_TESTING: alekzonder/puppeteer:latest
  IMG_TESTING_FINAL: node:8.9.1
  IMG_GITLAB_CI: juristr/angular-ci-build:1.0.0
  IMG_TESTING_GITLAB: alekzonder/puppeteer:latest
  IMG_TESTING_GITLAB2: buildkite/puppeteer

deploy_test:
  stage: test
  image: ${IMG_TESTING_GITLAB2}
  environment: Production
  cache:
    policy: pull
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test-ci
```

with package config

```
"test-ci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I was having the same issue - not able to launch the browser in headless mode

following worked for me

```
image: node:12
stages:
   - Test

Test:
stage: ApiTest
before_script:
  - echo "installing  dependency"
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
  - npm i
script:
 - echo "start the test"
 - npm test
only:
refs:
  - master
  - tags
```

puppeteer config - launch it with headless mode

```
 /* configurable options or object for puppeteer */
const opts = {
    headless: true,
    slowMo: 10,
    timeout: 0,
    args: ['--start-maximized', '--window-size=1920,1040','--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] 
}
```